# Silverlight: Uncached Children elemetn getting cached by SL runtime

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Silverlight: I have a parent cached Canvas element having uncached children element having opacity animation.

The silverlight runtime automaticaly makes these children elements cached.

How can I explicitly stop these childrent elements getting cached by SL runtime

Answer (score 0):

Please try set CacheMode="{x:Null}" in your child elements.